# Sorting ICollections in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity with a one-to-many relationship. But I need the child collection to be in a certain order. Here's an example:

```
public class Course
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students{get;set;}
}
public class Student
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public decimal Grade{get;set;}
}
```

Using the keyword `virtual`causes lazy-loading of the `Students` collection, so when I serialize it as JSON and send it through a Web API it essentially auto-populates the list of students. But, I always need those students to be in a certain order, such as in order of grade from highest to lowest. Here's what I came up with:

```
var course=db.Courses.Find(id);
course.Students=course.Students.OrderByDescending(s=>s.Grade).ToArray();
```

This seems to work but I worry that it's not the most efficient approach.

So my questions are: is there a better approach to ensuring that the child collection has a specified order? Assuming that I *always* want the child collection to be in this order, should I not specify `virtual` and avoid lazy-loading? Do the answers change if the sort order is more complex than can be contained in an `OrderBy` clause (eg, put students in order by year, then within each year order by grade)?

Comment: This is probably the most efficient way. You can't sort eager/lazyloaded data right away, maybe you can skip the `ToArray` call though. Just make sure to eager load the data though, right now you are making 2 db calls which is way more inefficient than sorting a collection in memory.

Comment: Thanks. The `ToArray` or something similar appears to be necessary because otherwise the compiler throws an error--"`IOrderedEnumerable` cannot be implicitly cast..."

Comment: Aah yes, should've thought of that. If you really want to remove a split second, use `ToList`, it's a little bit faster because `ToArray` has to calculate exact size :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I did some testing and based on Derck's answer this is what I ended up doing:

```
var course=db.Courses.Include(x=>x.Students).SingleOrDefault(x=>x.ID==id);
course.Students=course.Students.OrderByDescending(s=>s.Grade).ToList();
```

For a bit of explanation: there does not appear to be any way to write a linq whery that sorts child collections (CarbineCoder's answer still did not work), this has to be done separately. To prevent multiple database calls, I used the `Include` clause which eager-loaded the `Students` collection so that it could be sorted in memory. `Include` cannot be used with `Find` which is why I used `SingleOrDefault`. However, `OrderBy` is not a mutator method which is why Seabizkit's answer didn't quite work--you have to set the collection equal to the result returned by `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eager-Loading by adding Include statement to your query to fetch the data. If you use lazy-loading it will always load the data whether you need it or not.

```
db.Courses.Include(x=>x.Students)
          .SingleOrDefault(x => x== id) 
          .OrderByDescending(s=>s.Students.Grade).ToArray();
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. `Find` doesn't work with `Include` at all, at least according to the visual studio compiler, and the `OrderByDescending` would only order properties of `Course` not of `Student`

Answer (score 0):

try this, should work...

```
 var data =  db.Courses.Include(x=>x.Students)
                 .SingleOrDefault(x=>x.ID == id);

 data.Students.OrderByDescending(x => x.Grade);
```

if you were doing this for many courses you could do something like

```
var data =  db.Courses.Include(x=>x.Students)
             .Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("high"))
              .ToList();

List<Courses> res = data.ForEach(x => x.Students = x.Students
                                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Grade)
                                        .ToList())
                                        .ToList();
```

result will be a course with all the students.